# ClassNotFoundException when trying to show Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

I am trying to show a MapFragment, when I run my project in debug mode and I see a a `ClassNotFoundException` when the map tries to load. (**THERE IS NO STACKTRACE WRITTEN TO THE LOGCAT**)

The only thing I do see is this warning in the logcat

```
03-11 11:58:52.465: W/dalvikvm(16989): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1363 (common_google_play_services_install_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
```

When I look at the error in debug mode it looks like it is looking for the class `com.google.android.gms.R$string`

It does not even hit my breakpoint in the `onCreate` or the `onCreateView` but the map does load up. The problem is calling `getMap()` always returns null

I think it has something to do with google play services because if I call

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
```

I get the same problem. I know I have google play service installed on my tablet so I dont know what the problem is?

Comment: Do you have either the support library or the google-play-services_lib as a library for your project?

Comment: @akhalsa I copied the google-play-services library over to the lib folder of my project if thats what you mean

Comment: try cleaning your project, and then android tools -> fix project propeties

Comment: is it the .jar file or just the uncompiled library that you put in your libs folder?

Comment: @akhalsa the jar file, I see that it has to be imported as a library project, did that and it works now